# How do You Change Content in CSS When Hovering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I replace text with `CSS` using `content`?

Also just FYI don't worry about the `.fab` or Font Awesome unless you also know how to fix that. And if you can fix the JavaScript that'd be great too.

To use Font Awesome in your HTML put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

in your head tag.

```css
.sell {
  margin: -20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FDFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FDFEFE;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.styff {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styff:hover:after {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "This is currently not available in the App Store \f370";
}

.fab {
  color: #29B6F6;
}
```

```html
<div class="sell">
  <p class="styff">Buy now in the App Store <i class="fab fa-app-store-ios fa-lg"></i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This issue has been fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need two versions of content for hovering and normal.

```css
.sell {
  margin: -20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FDFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FDFEFE;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.styff {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*.styff:hover:after {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "This is currently not available in the App Store \f370";
}*/

.fab {
  color: #29B6F6;
}
/* that's new */
.sell:hover .styff.hide_on_hover {
  display: none;
}
.sell .styff.on_hover_only {
  display: none;
}
.sell:hover .styff.on_hover_only {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sell">
  <p class="styff hide_on_hover">Buy now in the App Store <i class="fab fa-app-store-ios fa-lg"></i></p>
  <p class="styff on_hover_only">Not buy for your sane!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.sell {
  margin: -20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FDFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FDFEFE;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.styff {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styff:after {
  content: 'Buy now in the App Store';
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styff:hover:after {
  content: "This is currently not available in the App Store";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="sell">
  <p class="styff"><i class="fab fa-app-store-ios fa-lg"></i></p>
</div>
```

You can use `:before` & `:after` pseudo elements for this.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following

```
  .styff:hover{
    font-size:0;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bqgfn56o/

Comment: It will set font-size 0 to pseudo elements too

Comment: Check the fiddle, it does not (since font-size is already set on after) (sry for not including it before)

Answer (score -1):

Add additional span to to your HTML, on hover hide that span:

```css
.sell {
  margin: -20px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FDFEFE;
  border: 2px solid #FDFEFE;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.styff {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styff:hover .text-to-hide {
  display: none;
}
.styff:hover:after {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Font Awesome 5 Free;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content: "This is currently not available in the App Store \f370";
}

.fab {
  color: #29B6F6;
}
```

```html
<div class="sell">
  <p class="styff"><span class="text-to-hide">Buy now in the App Store</span>
  <i class="fab fa-app-store-ios fa-lg"></i></p>
</div>
```